# Fabricjs and don't loaded canvas

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs

I've a problem with canvas.loadFromDatalessJSON(savedDataDLJSON) in fabricjs. When I have canvas with my simple rectangle all is good, but when i  added img(simple image), canvas don't  want to loaded(rectangle and image), i don't have any error. So i displayed json and i think it's normaly, i changed src to 'my_link_to_image' but image src is correct.

```
{"objects":[{"type":"rect","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":100,"top":100,"width":100,"height":100,"fill":"red","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":5,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"selectable":true,"hasControls":true,"hasBorders":true,"hasRotatingPoint":true,"transparentCorners":true,"perPixelTargetFind":false,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"rx":0,"ry":0,"x":0,"y":0},{"type":"image","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":314,"top":101,"width":70,"height":70,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"selectable":true,"hasControls":true,"hasBorders":true,"hasRotatingPoint":true,"transparentCorners":true,"perPixelTargetFind":false,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"src":"http://my_link_to_image","filters":[]}],"background":"cyan"}
```

Save and load click event

```
    $("#save").click(function() {
    savedDataDLJSON = JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON())
    canvas.clear();
});

$("#load").click(function(){
    console.log(savedDataDLJSON);
    canvas.loadFromDatalessJSON(savedDataDLJSON);
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Comment: use canvas.toJSON(), and canvas.loadFromJSON() instead

Comment: You know what ? I change my version fabric on the newest from https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js and it's working, i don't know how long but work :D

Comment: Nice! I have been through this kind of thing before :D